# Retrieving a single image from multiple subdirectories with PHP

Tags: php, image, file, random, directory

My PHP is clearly not that great, I'm using a seemingly slow method to retrieve images from subfolders in a folder called gallery/. What I'd like, ideally, is a single image (not every image) is chosen at random from any one of the subdirectories, and is displayed in a little HTML tag. I know about glob(), but I can't get it to work the way I want, so here's what I've been using to just pull every single image from the subfolders:

```
<?php

echo "<html><head></head><body>";

function ListFiles($dir) {
    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        $files = Array();
         $inner_files = Array();
        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files);
                } else {
                    array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        shuffle($files);
        return $files;
    }
}
foreach (ListFiles('gallery') as $key=>$file){
    echo "<div class=\"box\" style=\"margin: 3px;border: 1px dotted #999; display: inline-    block; \"><img src=\"$file\"/></div>";
}



echo "</body></html>";

?>
```

This is nice but it's not very scalable, and I know glob can be used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so here's what I've done, and it works quite well...

```
// Collects every path name under gallery/ for a .png
$imgs = glob("gallery/*/*.png");

//Mixes up the array
shuffle($imgs);
//Print it out just to make sure
//print_r($imgs);

//array_rand returns single key values, making it perfect to return a *single* image
$k = array_rand($imgs);
$v = $imgs[$k];

//Print out images
echo "<div class=\"box\" style=\"margin: 3px;border: 1px dotted #999; display: inline-block; \"><img src=\"$v\"/></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

See [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and look after examples of it.